# Drop-down list of year from 1970-present Access Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access, I'm trying to create a table Field called "Signed Year" which has to be from 1970 to present (currently 1970-2018) using Lookup Wizard. However, I realised it's not optimal since I have to manually add one more year from time to time.

Is there a code of some sort to automatically generate such ranges?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback list for this. Here is code for one listing ultimo dates 15 years back:

```
Public Function ListUltimoYears( _
  ctl As Control, _
  lngId As Long, _
  lngRow As Long, _
  lngCol As Long, _
  intCode As Integer) _
  As Variant

  ' Period for listing dates.
  Const cintYears               As Integer = 15

  ' 2014-09-24. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Static datFirstDate   As Date
  Static strFormat      As String
  Static intRows        As Integer

  Dim datDate           As Date
  Dim varValue          As Variant

  Select Case intCode
    Case acLBInitialize
      datDate = Date
      datFirstDate = DateSerial(Year(datDate), 12, 31)
      intRows = 1 + cintYears
      strFormat = ctl.Format
      varValue = True               ' True to initialize.
    Case acLBOpen
      varValue = Timer              ' Autogenerated unique ID.
    Case acLBGetRowCount            ' Get rows.
      varValue = intRows            ' Set number of rows.
    Case acLBGetColumnCount         ' Get columns.
      varValue = 1                  ' Set number of columns.
    Case acLBGetColumnWidth         ' Get column width.
      varValue = -1                 ' Use default width.
    Case acLBGetValue               ' Get the data for each row.
      varValue = DateAdd("yyyy", lngRow, datFirstDate)
    Case acLBGetFormat              ' Format the data.
      varValue = strFormat          ' Use format of control.
    Case acLBEnd
      ' Do something when form with listbox closes or
      ' listbox is requeried.
  End Select

  ' Return Value.
  ListUltimoYears = varValue

End Function
```

Modify it from using:

```
Const cintYears               As Integer = 15
```

to use a variable:

```
Dim intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", #1/1/1970#, Date)
```

To use it in a form, set the combobox' property *RowSourceType*: ListUltimoYears